# How to change Contact Form sendto from admin dynamically

Tags: emails

In D7 I have a hook_form_alter to make changes to the Contact Form (Core). How can I  change the sendto address from the admin to another email addres that is determined when the user requests the form?

Answer (score 2):

The core contact form is pretty limited in functionality. If you need more features, I recommend building your own form using the [Webform](http://drupal.org/project/webform) module.